# Use java Stream and Lambda expressions for nested loop

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

i want to replace the below code with the Streams and lambda expression

```
List < Obj > list=service.getList();
double value = 0.0;  
 for(int i=0;i<100;i++){  
  if((i+12)<100){
  for(int j=i;j<i + 12 ; j++){   
   value=1+value*Double.parseDouble(list.get(j).getValue())
   }
   }
  }
}
```

is there any best way to do it ?

Comment: what is `j + 12` for an exit condition in your for loop? :o

Comment: Yeah he probably wants to write `i + 12` since `j + 12` will never be true.

Comment: yeah, its i+12, let me edit it

Comment: did you mean `j < i + 12`?

Comment: I'm not even sure `i + 12` makes any sense and if that is even a valid boolean condition in Java.

Comment: well how the questions looks now, you can do that with streams, but that ain't pretty or any better than what you have now, so why want you do that?

Comment: …and this is a real life task?

Comment: yes, it is @Holger

Comment: @xander thought it would be more readable and less confusing

Comment: It is your idea of the task itself that is confusing. Just converting to a Stream won’t help you, as long as you don’t clean up the task itself. You are performing unnecessary and repeated work, e.g. you are calculating `Double.parseDouble(list.get(j).getValue())` for `j==0`, just to multiply the result with zero; for other elements, you are repeating that (expensive) operation up to twelve times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
List<Obj> list = service.getList();
double value = IntStream.range(0, 100 - 12)
    .flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(i, i + 12))
    .mapToDouble(j -> Double.parseDouble(list.get(j).getValue()))
    .reduce(0, (acc, e) -> 1 + acc * e);
```

Comment: Does the reduce method run 100 times or is it going to run for 12 times?

Comment: @SandeepSingh It's going to run (100 - 12) * 12 times, just like your code. 100 times for the outer loop, minus the times when `i + 12 >= 100` (which is 12 times), and 12 times for the inner loop.

Comment: It was nice to get rid of the 12 last trivial loops.

Comment: While this may work in a sequential context, it is not a correct usage of this API. `0` is not an identity element of this reduction function and the function is not associative.

Comment: @JornVernee :Thank you so much that helps

Comment: Getting rid of the obsolete last 12 iterations works with loops too and `double value = 0.0; for(int i=0; i<100-12;i++) for(int j=i; j < i+12; j++) value=1+value*Double.parseDouble( list.get(j).getValue());` is significantly shorter than the stream solution and it’s not abusing an API. But as said the [other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43049942/use-java-stream-and-lambda-expressions-for-nested-loop#comment73186846_43049942), performing expensive operations like `Double.parseDouble` up to twelve times for the same input, is the issue, not whether the code uses loop or streams…